# Why are these undefined variables not equal javascript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Suppose I have the following event handler:

```
function handleCsvDump(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('download'));
    e.currentTarget.download = undefined;
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('download'));
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('download') === undefined);
```

The information logged to the console when the corresponding button is clicked is:

```
mycsv.csv
undefined
false
```

Why is the last value `false`?  Since `e.currentTarget.getAttribute('download')` is `undefined`, shouldn't it be true?  If this is the wrong way to go about this, how can I test whether a variable is undefined?

Comment: Look at [the documentation for getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute): *getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string);*

Comment: Are you sure that when you did `download = undefined`, it didn't coerce it to a string, and actually set the value to `"undefined"`.  Does your console log look like `"mycsv.csv", "undefined", false` or `"mycsv.csv", undefined, false`?

Comment: James, the console log was like `mycsv.csv`. `undefined`, `false`.  There were not quotation marks.

Comment: Okay apparently it actually did get coerced to a string.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You won't necessarily see quotation marks, it was meant to be an illustration of whether it was logging `undefined` as a string, or actually undefined.  You should be able to tell the difference between the two, be it through being different colours or quote marks or what, depending on the console implementation.

Comment: Ahh, that's a good call.  `undefined` was being shown in black - as a string would be; I didn't catch that.  If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I'd be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful when setting things this way, often things are expected to be strings, and if you set a value that isn't a string, it will first be coerced to a string, then assigned.

The [`download` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-a-element:dom-a-download) is indeed a DOMString, meaning that anything you assign to it will first be coerced to a string if it isn't already, so when you assign `undefined`, it's actually first coerced to `"undefined"` and that is stored.

When you get it back out, and compare it to `undefined`, you're actually doing:

```
console.log("undefined" === undefined)
```

Hence getting `false`.  If you do actually want to remove it, which is implied by wanting to set it to `undefined` (or `null`), you can instead use [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute):

```
e.currentTarget.removeAttribute('download')
```